# How to configure code signing identity from terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, code-signing

I'm trying to set up Travis CI for an iOS application. Got the following error:

> Code Sign error: No matching codesigning identity found: No
>   codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs)
>   matching “iPhone Developer” were found.

I would normally log into Xcode with my portal credentials, or I would manually set things up using Keychain Access.app. But I can't use a GUI on the Travis boxes.

How can I configure my signing identity from the command line?

Comment: This is an older question, but I think the best way to do this now is to use `fastlane match`. https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/

Answer (score 4):

1. export your certificate and identity from keychain access as a .p12 file
2. unlock keychain

   security unlock-keychain -p LOGIN_USER_PASSWORD
3. import .p12 file

   security import YOUR_P12_FILE_PATH -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain -P YOUR_P12_PASSWORD -T /usr/bin/codesign